# add escape functionality in wordpress __( function

Tags: wordpress, localization, escaping

I would like in translation function __( defined as :

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate( $text, $domain );
}
```

to add escape functionality, I mean something like adding 3rd parameter( $esc_wrapper='html' ), by which output text would be wrapped in esc_html(, or in esc_url or in esc_js or in esc_attr,
depending on this 3rd paremeter.
Questions are:
1) which is the best way to override this __( function ?
2) If there are some good tools/libs for this ?
3) Do you think my idea good, say if I make some plugin for backend and frontend? Wouldn't it be better to make my own function with translating and escaping functions ? I am really new in wp...
  WordPress 4.2 Beta 3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use **"esc_attr__"** it is built for the same reason to escape and translate the text.

```
<?php esc_attr__( $text, $domain ) ?>
```